# How to print Bibtex entry volume with uppercase V

Tags: bibtex

I'm using Bibtex and would like to cite a book that is part of a series. The relevant entry in my bib.bib file is

```
@book{key,
author = {author},
title = {title},
series = {series title},
volume = {1: volume title},
publisher = {publisher},
year = {2015}
}
```

Instead of "volume 1: volume_title of series_title" I would like to have "Volume 1: volume_title of series_title" while keeping the format, i.e. have "series_title" printed in italics, but not "volume_title".

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside,fleqn]{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib} 

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\mainmatter

\backmatter

\bibliography{bib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\nocite{*}

\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance.

Regards, Sebastian

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what you have to do.

Save a copy of `plainnat.bst` as `myplainnat.bst` in your document directory. The path of `plainnat.bst` is `TEXMF/bibtex/bst/natbib/`.

Then open `myplainnat.bst` in your editor and search for the lines:

```
FUNCTION {format.bvolume}
{ volume empty$
    { "" }
    { "volume" volume tie.or.space.connect
      series empty$
        'skip$
        { " of " * series emphasize * }
      if$
      "volume and number" number either.or.check
    }
  if$
}
```

Replace them with the following

```
FUNCTION {format.bvolume}
{ volume empty$
    { "" }
    { "Volume" volume tie.or.space.connect
      series empty$
        'skip$
        { " of " * series emphasize * }
      if$
      "Volume and number" number either.or.check
    }
  if$
}
```

and save the file.

Now in your document, replace

```
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
```

with

```
\bibliographystyle{myplainnat}
```

and you're done.

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside,fleqn]{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\mainmatter

\backmatter

\bibliography{bib}
\bibliographystyle{myplainnat}
\nocite{*}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I'm sure this works but I can't find the plainnat.bst file. There is a TeX folder in applications, but it doesn't contain any of the folders mentioned in your path. I installed MacTeX and TexMaker separately and haven't changed anything since.

Comment: @Sebastian_92 Probably the directory is `/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/natbib/`

Comment: @Sebastian_92 If you haven't find it yet, run `kpsewhich plainnat.bst` in the terminal to see its path.

Comment: Cheers, found the file and it works. :)

Comment: @Sebastian_92 Happy about that.